# trouble running mysqldump on Ubuntu via cron job

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I'm trying to set up a cron job to back up my database every night at midnight. Based on a few tutorials I've read, I've written a script that executes the following command:

```
mysqldump -u my_username --all-databases | gzip -9 > $filename
```

I don't want my password added to the command for security reasons, so I created a .my.cnf file in my home directory that looks like this:

```
[mysqldump]
user = my_username
password = my_password
```

The problem is, whenever I run mysqldump, I get the following message:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'my_username'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect
```

I've even tried adding `--defaults-file="/home/my_username/.my.cnf"` to the command, but it doesn't help. Is there something else I need to be doing? Does mysqldump handle configurations differently in Ubuntu? Please understand that I have tried reading the manuals, but I can't make head nor tail of them--waaaaay too much information to sift through.

Comment: Have you tried grabbing the output of `mysqldump --print-defaults` in the cron job to make sure it's running as you expect?

Comment: What was the problem then ?

Comment: There was a hash mark in my password; the .my.cfg interpreted it as a comment. I changed my password and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

There are no privileges for this user. My SQl expects that you add an entry in the user table for each "user" + "host" combination. In your case the user table does not contain an entry for the my_username@localhost. You might say that it contains an entry for my_username@127.0.0.1 but mysql doesn't consider both to be the same.

The best way to add an entry in this table is to grant privileges to my_username@localhost.

Comment: That's strange. I just opened up phpmyadmin and checked out the privileges page, and it says that my_username@localhost has all privileges. Do I need to do this separately for mysqldump too?

Comment: Can you run a SELECT on the users and Pastebin it. (mask the userid and email)